# Why there are a lot of heap fetches after vacuum full and no heap fetches after vacuum? (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

The questing regarding Postgres DBMS.

1. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings
(
    book_ref character(6) NOT NULL,
    book_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    total_amount numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT bookings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (book_ref)
)
```

Autovacuum job is disabled.

2. I run the following query where query planner decided to do index only scan:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS OFF, TIMING OFF)
SELECT book_ref FROM bookings WHERE book_ref <= '100000';
```

The query plan is:
[image: query plan without heap fetches]
There are no heap fetches.

3. I run the update command:

```
update bookings 
set total_amount = 1000 
where book_ref in (
    select book_ref
    from bookings
    limit 100
    );
```

And for now I have 295 heap fetches

[image: 295 heap fetches]

4. Then I run the vacuum full command and there are a lot of heap fetches.
   [image: a lot of heap fetches]
5. Then I run the vacuum command and there are no heap fetches.
   [image: no heap fetches again]

The questions are:

1. Why there are a lot of heap fetches after vacuum full?
2. Why vacuum without vacuum full does not work and there are heap fetches still after vacuum without vacuum full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `VACUUM (FULL)` does something entirely different from `VACUUM`.

`VACUUM` removes dead tuples, updates the visibility map and the free space map and freezes tuples.

`VACUUM (FULL)` creates a new copy of the table, with the surviving rows densely packed. It *deletes* the visibility map, which causes all these heap fetches.

In short: always use `VACUUM`. `VACUUM (FULL)` is reorganization you can only perform in a maintenance window if necessary.